# scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to train a neural network model,and this is part of the code to centre the image,the problem is when i run this piece of code-

```
def centering_image(img):
  size = [256,256]

  img_size = img.shape[:2]

  # centering
  row = (size[1] - img_size[0]) // 2
  col = (size[0] - img_size[1]) // 2
  resized = np.zeros(list(size) + [img.shape[2]], dtype=np.uint8)
  resized[row:(row + img.shape[0]), col:(col + img.shape[1])] = img

  return resized


x = []
for i, file_path in enumerate(file_paths):
  #read image
  img = cv2.imread(file_path)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

  #resize
  if(img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]):
    tile_size = (int(img.shape[1]*256/img.shape[0]),256)
  else:
    tile_size = (256, int(img.shape[0]*256/img.shape[1]))

  #centering
  img = centering_image(cv2.resize(img, dsize=tile_size))

  #out put 224*224px 
  img = img[16:240, 16:240]
  x.append(img)

x = np.array(x)
```

I get this error-

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-11-2a14d86a9a00> in <module>()
 17     #read image
 18     img = cv2.imread(file_path)
---> 19     img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 20 
 21     #resize

error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9716: error: (-215) 
scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor`
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?or just bored?

Comment: after imread test whether an image was loaded successfully. Probably there is an illegal path or a non-image file in your list.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It seems like one of your loaded images has four channels. Therefore the color conversion from BGR to RBG does not work, because it expects three channels.</strike>

You could use the `cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR` flag instead.

The errors says that `cvtColor` with the `COLOR_BGR2RGB` expects an image with 3 or 4 channels, but got something different. So you should double-check the number of channels with `print img.shape`.

Comment: any tips on what i can change?

Comment: You could try `cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the error message properly. It says that you image does not have 3 or 4 channels. So maybe it's a gray scale image. Check with `print img.shape`.

Comment: its a color image,866, 1154, 3)

Comment: Okay, that's weird. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L9716) it simply checks the number of channels. Your code suggests that you're loading multiple images. Can you double check that they have 3 or 4 channels?

Comment: Fixed it.the number of images didnt match up to the labels,thats why it was throwing an error,thanks for your time though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151688/discussion-between-jjdoe-and-ryan).